# RegEx help needed to identify sentences

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this:

**"Mark**

**Whatever sentence**
**Whatever sentence 2**

**Matt**

**Whatever sentence 3**
**Whatever sentence 4**

**Carol**

**Whatever sentence 5**
**Whatever sentence 6"**

I want to be able to identify each sentence (and then make a list of each sentence). How can I do this in a easy way?

It doesn't matter if Mark, Matt and Carol are identified and later added to the list because those names are always the same but the sentences can differ.

I've tried a bit, but I can't figure out how to deal with the empty lines...

Any help would be much appreciated even if it's just a pointer to head me in the right direction..

Comment: How do you differentiate between a sentence and a name? Can you give a more specific example and your expected output (matches)? What exactly have you tried already?

Comment: @slhck the OP doesn't (I think). "It doesn't matter if Mark, Matt and Carol are identified" ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you don't need a regex.

Just use [splitlines](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
>>> text = """Mark

Whatever sentence
Whatever sentence 2

Matt

Whatever sentence 3
Whatever sentence 4

Carol

Whatever sentence 5
Whatever sentence 6"""
>>> sentences = text.splitlines()
>>> sentences
['Mark', '', 'Whatever sentence', 'Whatever sentence 2', '', 'Matt', '', 'Whatever sentence 3', 'Whatever sentence 4', '', 'Carol', '', 'Whatever sentence 5', 'Whatever sentence 6']
```

Then [filter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) out all the blank lines:

```
>>> sentences = list(filter(None, sentences))
>>> sentences
['Mark', 'Whatever sentence', 'Whatever sentence 2', 'Matt', 'Whatever sentence 3', 'Whatever sentence 4', 'Carol', 'Whatever sentence 5', 'Whatever sentence 6']
```

If by "make a list of each sentence", you mean split each sentence into words, you could do this:

```
>>> sentences = [sentence.split() for sentence in sentences]
>>> sentences
[['Mark'], ['Whatever', 'sentence'], ['Whatever', 'sentence', '2'], ['Matt'], ['Whatever', 'sentence', '3'], ['Whatever', 'sentence', '4'], ['Carol'], ['Whatever', 'sentence', '5'], ['Whatever', 'sentence', '6']]
```

Comment: I was expecting to get some kind of answer but not this fast and definitely not this kick-ass! 
Thanks man, I'll try it out!

Comment: The answer I was on the point to post ! You should precise that, using ``list(filter(...))`` ,  the code is in Python 3, isn't it ?

Comment: @user3024863 Then you should click on the "bracket" that is under the 'upvote button - points - downvote button' series at the left of the answer of seeneyrod, to accept it

Comment: @eyquem Yes, I tested with Python 3.3, but I don't think there's any difference between it and Python 2.7 in this case.

Comment: In Python 2, ``list(filter(...))`` works but is redundant since ``filter()`` returns a list when the argument is a list

Answer (score 1):

If all sentences end with a newline, you can use this (very simple) regular expression:

```
/([^\n]+)/
```

Tip: you can use http://rubular.com/ to test your regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this if needed. Not sure which way I will go yet, but this might come handy later on.